# Why is Python not reading past this thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

Stack Overflow! Perhaps I have missed a crucial detail, but it seems that Python 3 is not reading up to the comment in the code indicated below. I'm attempting to start threads for each client that connects to the server so that more than one client has the capability to connect to the server. This is the snippet of code that I found to be problematic for me, because, as the prints indicate, it seems that Python is not even taking a glance at the rest of it.

```
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(f"{addr} has joined the server.")
        clientsocket_list.append(conn)
        print("Adding client to list")
        #Based on which prints are actually printing, it seems Python is only reading up to here.
        clientthread(conn, addr)
        print("Using clientthread")
        client_thread_thread = threading.Thread(target=clientthread(conn, addr))
        print(f"Starting new thread for {conn}, Thread #{threads}")
        client_thread_thread.start()
        threads += 1
        client_thread_thread.join()
```

Any help would be appreciated a lot, thank you! Also, I apologize if I left anything crucial out, this is one of my first questions on Stack, so I'm still settling in a little! Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it isn't getting stuck in `clientthread(conn, addr)`?

Comment: Please share more information about the problem. Also as @Craig said, how do you know that it is not stuck in `clientthread(conn, addr)`?